# VS2010 Database Server Project Machine Name Variable

Tags: visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005, windows-authentication

Using a Visual Studio 2010 SQL Server Database Project, is there anyway to use the current machine name in a SQL script? For instance, I'd like to create a Windows login:

```
CREATE LOGIN [$(MachineName)\Username] FROM WINDOWS;
```

I've tried using `[.\Username]`, `[localhost\Username]`, `[BuiltIn\Username]` and `[LocalMachine\Username]` but I get an error during deployment; it seems the full machine name is required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I ended up doing in case someone else needs to do this.

1. Create a build configuration for each region (Development, QA, UAT, Production).
2. Create a `Properties\Database.[Region].sqlcmdvars` for each region.
3. Go to the database project's Properties, Deploy tab and choose the proper SQL command variables file for the currently selected configuration.
4. Repeat for all other configurations.
5. Don't check in your `Database.Development.sqlcmdvars` file because that should be unique per developer machine.

Answer (score 0):

You could dynamically build the SQL statement after you connect.

```
DECLARE @userName NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @machineName NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @command NVARCHAR(MAX)
SELECT @machineName = CAST(SERVERPROPERTY('MachineName') AS NVARCHAR(MAX))
SET @userName = @machineName + '\UserA'

SET @command = 'CREATE LOGIN [' + @userName + '] FROM WINDOWS;'

EXEC sp_executesql @command
```

Comment: I suppose that would work, however, it wouldn't validate the core statement during the build - a minor downside. The answer I posted seems to work and would allow for the user to reside on a different machine than the SQL Server. And for different configurations to exist per region/developer. Thanks for the answer!